# Android Studio - Where is Kotlin installed?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have macosx and I would like to use `kotlin` from terminal. Then I would like to find where is `kotlin` installed, since I'm using it from Android Studio.

I know i can install `Kotlin` using `homebrew` but I want avoid having two copies of `Kotlin`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The kotlin that is bundled with AS can be found here

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin/kotlinc
```

Answer (score 4):

I have Android Studio installed and I found the Kotlin location within `~/home/<user>/AS/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin`.

Current OS : Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 (Android 4.1 at least)

```
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\bin\kotlinc.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had Kotlin installation coming from my Android Studio.

```
Android Studio 2022.3.1

Windows 11
```

I found it from the path:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\bin
```